# bigram occurences to dictionary python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, combinations, counter, find-occurrences

I would like to iterate through the list:

```
inc_list = ['one', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'three']
```

and create a dictionary that shows all bigrams of neighboring words and the number their occurrences, while counting reversed order combinations as equal so reversed combinations and exclude same word combinations.
So `..'one', 'two'..` as well as `..'two', 'one'..` should both add to the count of `('one', 'two')` in the dictionary.

expected output:

```
{('one', 'two'): 3, ('one', 'three'): 2, ('two', 'three'): 1}
```

So far I have tried with:

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter

inc_list = ['one', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'three',]

coocurences = dict(Counter(itertools.combinations(inc_list, 2)))

print(coocurences)
```

This obviously counts all combination possibilities while including reversed as well as same word combinations, so not what I am looking for.

Is there a tool in itertools that does something closer to my desired output?

I have found a lot of information about co-occurrence matrices, however I would prefer a dictionary as output.

Comment: How do you differentiate which combination is included? I mean when is it one_two and when is it two_one..

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, you need to define the ordering of the pairs if you just want to add one. Here is one possibility:

```py
from collections import Counter

inc_list = ['one', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'three',]

bigrams = Counter()
for previous, current in zip(inc_list, inc_list[1:]):
    opt1 = (f"{previous}", f"{current}")
    opt2 = (f"{current}", f"{previous}")
    if opt2 not in bigrams:
        bigrams[opt1] += 1
        continue
    bigrams[opt2] += 1
coocurences = dict(bigrams)
print(coocurences)
```

output:

```
{('one', 'two'): 3, ('one', 'three'): 2, ('three', 'two'): 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the quick response and the great suggestion. I modified it a little to give me exactly what I needed.

```
from collections import Counter

inc_list = ['one', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'three',]

bigrams = Counter()
for previous, current in zip(inc_list, inc_list[1:]):
    opt1 = f"{previous}", f"{current}"
    opt2 = f"{current}", f"{previous}"
    if opt2 not in bigrams:
        bigrams[opt1] += 1
        continue
    bigrams[opt2] += 1
coocurences = dict(bigrams)
print(coocurences)
```

this puts out:

```
{('one', 'two'): 3, ('one', 'three'): 2, ('three', 'two'): 1}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry I missed the formatting detail. Been working on _ separated bigrams myself. Updated to match your requested output. Accept? :)

Comment: No problem. Your suggestion made it work so all props to you. Have a great sunday